# Add a tomcat railo vhost without restarting tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, railo

Is there a way to add a vhost entry in tomcats server.xml or elsewhere without restarting the tomcat server like a reload signal supported by webservers etc.

I am working on a shared hosting control panel extension for railo appserver and requirement of a restart for any changes made by users in a shared environment is a big deterrent

Answer (score 0):

Check out the mod_cfml project over at http://modcfml.org.

The Railo4cPanel project (which sounds similar to what you're doing) also uses mod_cfml:
https://github.com/utdream/Railo4cPanel

Comment: Thanks. But I am using an nginx server to reverse proxy to the railo app server .so cannot use apache connectors